# linq and string of array problem. Try to find elements in string of array

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array `string[] data` with 512 items. Can I use LINQ to find all elements that contain the string `"tx"`?

I did try `data.Where` but it was not a valid statement.

Comment: `Where()` expects a delegate/lambda expression.

Comment: you are right. I need lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file. data.Where should work just fine.

And you need to be using .NET 3.5 or above.

If you have this, then Jons answer should work perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Simple:

```
data.Where(s => s.Contains("tx"))
```

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE` should work fine!

```
 var filtered = data.Where(x => x.Contains("tx"));
```